# Keep same width/height ratio of a div with fluid design when appending with jQuery

Tags: css, height, width, fluid, responsive

Thank you for taking the time for this.

I want to achieve:

1. Fill the whole window with divs that should be squares.
2. There must be 20 squares per row.
3. I want to append them using jQuery when the page loads.
4. I want them to be responsive, for now I'm not taking into account mobile devices, where the screen goes from landscape to portrait. Onyl different widths of desktop devices.

Each one of them has a differenet color, so my javascript is a loop that .append() each different div to an HTML container.

This is the code inside the append:

```
"<div class='square' style='background-color:" + color + "; width:5%; height:????;'></div>"
```

I was hoping that the auto height would keep the square ratio, but it does not.
I could use jQuery to get the size on pixels of the div once it's appended, and then use that to set the height, but that approach makes me doubtful about responsiveness, as every time the window is resized I would have to do the same.

Any thoughts or ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `padding-bottom` trick to create a div with matching dimensions that is responsive.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/code4pi/rc5r8jvg/1/)

Comment: WHAT SORCERY IS THIS?? Worked as a charm, thank you very much sir!